# Does reduce not work with jQuery? How to count elements in a const variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I'd like to create a const variable that is equal to the number of checked checkboxes with a certain class. This is my code to do that(which is not working):

```
const blocksUserAddLineCBs = $(".useradd"+blockIdEnding);
const blocksUserAddLinesActiveCBCounter = blocksUserAddLineCBs.reduce((currentTotal, item) => {
    return $(item).prop('checked') === true + currentTotal;
}, 0);
```

Is the reduce method not working with a Field created with a jQuery Selector? How could i that without having to create a let Variable and a $().each Loop which increases the variable every time it recognizes one of the elements is checked `($(this).prop('checked'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.reduce` doesn't work on jQuery objects, and in any event it's overkill:

```
const count = $('.useradd' + blockIdEnding + ':checked').length;
```

or alternatively:

```
const $els = $('.useradd' + blockIdEnding);
const count = $els.filter(':checked').length;
```

(variables renamed to prevent window overflow)

Comment: Also `blocksUserAddLineCBs.filter(":checked").length` (same feature, using OPs existing const)

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, that's a good option if the list of all elements is also needed in later lines.

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` is a method found on arrays.

A jQuery object is not an array.

You can get an array from a jQuery object using its [`toArray` method](https://api.jquery.com/toarray/).